# Xcode unable to build to iPhone: Unable to locate a develop disk Image. IOS 17, Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15, ios17

I am using Xcode 15 and iPhone IOS version is 17.4. I am getting this error in Xcode while trying to build my application on iPhone:
[image]

I am aware of the answers provided in old questions already there in SO. I have tried all of them and one limitation is that I **can't update the Xcode** for some reasons.
Device Support files are not available for IOS 17 and above. And, Xcode 15 is supposed to work with iOS 17.

I found in SO and apple discuss forum that a lot of people are getting this issue with IOS 17 and Xcode 15. So I invite their findings and fixes to the questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Xcode 15.3 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15_3-release-notes):

> Xcode 15.3 includes SDKs for **iOS 17.4**, iPadOS 17.4, tvOS 17.4, watchOS 10.4, macOS Sonoma 14.4, and visionOS 1.1.

There was a workaround before: it's copy device support files into the `DeviceSupport` folder. However, it will not work from now on. Check Apple staff comment [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730947):

> Copying files from a newer version of Xcode to an older version of Xcode for any purpose was never supported. That it worked for your needs was coincidental.

So, IMHO, there is no way you can run a real iOS 17.4 device with a Xcode version that is lower than 15.3.